# In WinUI3, how do I know when the Window is loaded and visible to the user?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

In WinUI3, I am wanting to provide updates to the user of a Window during the loading of resources. Each time I am loading a resource, I would like to set the text of a TextBlock. I have tried setting the text directly, performing two way data binding and using INotifyPropertyChanged. But for the life of me, I cannot do something so simple as update the UI. And yes, I have searched high and low on the web, and nothing has worked.

Please provide me with a simple c# and xaml example that updates a textblock in realtime as I am loading resources. Thank you.

Here is what I've tried.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LoadingStackPanel"  >
    <ProgressRing x:Name="LoadingProgressRing" IsActive="True" IsHitTestVisible="True"  />
    <TextBlock x:Name="ProgressTextBlock" Text="{x:Bind Path=GetData, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Method 1:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _data = "Loading...";

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public string GetData
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GetData");
        }
    }
```

And then setting the `GetData` property.

Method 2:

```
ProgressTextBlock.Text = "Loading resource ...";
```

Method 3:

```
DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {
    ProgressTextBlock.Text = "Loading resource ...";
});
```

Method 4:

```
DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {
    GetData = "Loading resource ...";
});
```

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: I've edited my post to show you what I've tried as requested.

Comment: I am new to this, so all advise is welcome. I will use {Binding} instead of {x:Bind}. I set my control's datacontext to GetData, and I can see the ProgressRing and the textblock underneath it.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to accomplish what I need to do, and so I am posting my answer for anyone else who may be interested in the solution.

The following code will display the ProgressRing and a TextBlock. The Text of the TextBlock will be updated with the name of the website that is being loaded. When all the websites have been loaded, the progress indication panel is hidden and the home panel is shown.

The XAML:

```
<Window
        x:Class="CH11_ResponsiveWinUI3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:DefaultBindMode="TwoWay"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ProgressPanel">
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="ProgressUpdater" Text="Loading..." TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="HomePanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock Text="Home Window" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The Code Behind (**Edited as per the comments from @Clemens**):

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CH11_ResponsiveWinUI3
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _timer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _timer = new();
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
            await GetWebsitesAsync();
        }

        private List<string> WebsiteLinks()
        {
            List<string> websiteLinks = new();
            ProgressUpdater.Text = "Loading...";
            websiteLinks.Add("https://learn.microsoft.com");
            websiteLinks.Add("https://www.youtube.com");
            websiteLinks.Add("https://www.abovetopsecret.com/index.php");
            websiteLinks.Add("https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet");
            websiteLinks.Add("https://www.packtpub.com/free-learning");
            websiteLinks.Add("https://smile.amazon.com/");
            return websiteLinks;
        }

        private async Task GetWebsitesAsync()
        {
        Dictionary<string, string> websites = new();
        List<Task< Dictionary<string, string> >> tasks = new();

        foreach(string website in WebsiteLinks())
        {
            string contents = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(new Uri(website));
            websites.Add(website, contents);
            ProgressUpdater.Text = $"\nURL: {website}, downloaded...";
        }
        ProgressUpdater.Text = "\nLoading completed.";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        ProgressPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        HomePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000) in GetWebsitesAsync will block the UI for a second. Use `await Task.Delay(1000)` instead.

Comment: Do not create a WebClient for each download.

Comment: Use an async download method instead of running a synchronous download in a Task. For example HttpClient.GetStringAsync.

Comment: @Clemens, thank you for your comments. I will take onboard and apply your guidance.